# Creating a mapped type from an object without errors in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

How does one create a mapped type from an object? If I attempt the following:

```
interface Stats {
  count: number,
  avg: number
}

class Blah<T> {
  private stats: { [K in keyof T]: Stats };

  constructor(foo: T) {
    this.stats = Object
      .keys(foo)
      .reduce((result, key) => Object.assign(result, { 
        [key]: { count: 0, avg: 1 } 
      }), {});
  }
}
```

...I get the error:

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ [K in keyof T]: Stats; }'

This appears to be because the initial value in `reduce` is does not match the interface.

I can change my declaration this as a workaround:

```
private stats: { [K in keyof T]?: Stats };
```

...but that now means that some values for a keyof T may be undefined according to the type.

How do you create a fully mapped type, given the inability to create a mapped object without intermediate results in JavaScript?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tedious, but you can do the following:

```
interface Stats {
  count: number,
  avg: number
}

type StatsMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Stats };

class Blah<T> {
  public stats:StatsMap<T>;

  constructor(foo: T) {
    this.stats = Object
      .keys(foo)
      .reduce<StatsMap<T>>((result, key) => Object.assign(result, { 
        [key]: { count: 0, avg: 1 } 
      }), {} as any);
  }
}

const blah = new Blah({ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' });
console.log(blah.stats.a.avg); // Yay, no error + autocomplete!
```

The `{} as any` is required to tell TypeScript you know what you're doing :-/

You can [test this on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Stats%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20count%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20avg%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20StatsMap%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20Stats%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Blah%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20stats%3AStatsMap%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(foo%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.stats%20%3D%20Object%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.keys(foo)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.reduce%3CStatsMap%3CT%3E%3E((result%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20Object.assign(result%2C%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%5D%3A%20%7B%20count%3A%200%2C%20avg%3A%201%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%20%7B%7D%20as%20any)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20blah%20%3D%20new%20Blah(%7B%20a%3A%20'a'%2C%20b%3A%20'b'%2C%20c%3A%20'c'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(blah.stats.a.avg)%3B).

*Note that I made the `stats` memboer `public` to show the usage! This is not required or anything. You also do not have to create the `StatsMap`, but I find it easier to read compared to writing `{ [K in keyof T]: Stats }` multiple times.*